# Show that $\bigcup_{n\geq 1} A_n\subset B$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I have a rahter silly question.. but am a bit unsure nonetheless.
If I have to show that

$\bigcup_{n\geq 1} A_n\subset B$

is it enough to show that there is ONE $A_n$ with $A_n\subset B$?

Comment: no.  see example:  $A_1  =\{ 1 \} = B$, $A_2 = \{ 2\}$, then $A_1\cup A_2$ is not contained in $B$ while $A_1$ is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. If $A_1=\varnothing$, does that necessarily mean that $A_n\subseteq B=A_1=\varnothing$?

Answer (score 1):

You need prove that EVERY An pertenece a B